# What is the approximate row limit for an html table using jQuery DataTables before the page becomes too slow?

Tags: jquery, datatables

If you had an html table of 10 or so columns, 
and you apply the jQuery DataTables plugin to the table, 
at what point (approximately) should one expect 
the number of table rows to adversely affect browser-rendering
performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it really depends on what you're rendering in each table row element and how many columns you have. If you're just doing text, I've experienced slowdown after a few hundred rows, with a mysql server on the same machine as the webhost. If you're placing image elements or event handlers with each row, expect slowdown to happen with fewer rows. A good idea is to get a browser that easily shows you load times, like Chrome, Safari, and Firefox+firebug.

Comment: I agree. The number of rows before a slow down will occur will continue to change as browsers JavaScript engines continue to get faster as well.

Comment: Fair enough. What might also be useful is to have a chart comparing rendering speeds in different browsers and different browser versions, and even different grid plugins for the same table. Looks like someone attempted something similar once, but didn't keep it updated. http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/browserSpeed.html#winspeed